# CSS - How to make position:absolute work not on all 100% screens area

Tags: html, css

My `body` is 800px wide:

```
body {
width:800px;
margin:15px auto;}
```

I have a `<div>` area (100x200px) that should be in TOP RIGHT corner of the body, no matter what screen or browser opened it. I tried to do following:

```
#login-hover-cont{width:210px;padding:20px;position:absolute;right:0px;_right:-1px;top:30px;z-index:3;background:#fff}
```

It puts the `div` to TOP RIGHT corner of the SCREEN, which is wrong - I want it to be in the place where the right border of BODY is. How do I do that?
Don't feel like using "position:relative".

Comment: *Don't feel like using "position:relative"* — Why not and so what? Feelings aren't a reason to reject a technical solution. `position: relative` is the correct and standard way to achieve the effect you are asking for.

Comment: Agreed. Position: relative is the way to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `body` to this.

```
body 
{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

And your `div` will be inside the body and have styles similar to this.

```
#login-hover-cont
{
    ...
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

You need to do this because absolute positioning will always be relative to the elements nearest positioned ancestor.

Comment: This uses `position: relative` which the question explicitly vetos.

Comment: He meant using `position: relative` on the div `#login-hover-cont`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make the body 800px wide, leave it as auto width and place a container div around your absolutely positioned one. Give the container a width of 800px, and a postion:relative style definition. The positon absolute is then relative to your container div.

here is a working sample

http://jsfiddle.net/5a6Fu/

Comment: The question explicitly vetos `position: relative` (which isn't an attribute).

Comment: @Quentin the question vetos positon:relative on the div that he is trying to place, not the container. As you can see from the chosen answer, he chose position:relative on the body instead of a containing div.